# TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

`user` is a Mongoose entity object. I want to append some data on user, save it and just proceed to next `then()` after that entity has been successfully saved on DB. So I am doing:

```
User
  .findOne({ email: req.body.email })
  .then((user) => {
    user.data = ...;
    user = user.save().then(() => user);
    return user;
  })
  .then((user => ... /* continue after user has been saved */ ))
```

Yet, I am getting a `TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise` and I am not realizing how to solve my requirements.

Comment: Try replacing the user = ... and return user; with simply return user.save();

Comment: @maxpaj solution works fine. I thought the Promise returned by save() does not contain the saved document. But it does. It solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No problem dude :)

Comment: I am having same error but witout using any DB or ORM

Comment: I found out that this error can occour when resolve or reject are not handled in correct way